# Update the cache of Apollo client 3 when polling not working

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo-client, polling

I am playing with the cache of `@apollo/client` v3. Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/playing-with-apolloclient-3-cache-2d55b?file=/src/useGetOptionList.ts:290-302).

I am adding a **user** to a cached list of users using `client.writeQuery`, and the query has a `pollInterval` to refetch every few seconds.

I am able to add the user to the list, it does refresh the UI, and I can see the pollInterval working in the `network` tab of Chrome.

**THE PROBLEM**

I would expect the list of users to return to its initial state when the polling kicks in, and overwrite the user I added manually to the cache, but it does not.

**Apollo config**

```js
export const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: "https://fakeql.com/graphql/218375d695835e0850a14a3c505a6447"
  })
});
```

**UserList**

```js
export const UserList = () => {
  const { optimisticAddUserToCache, data, loading } = useUserList();

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => optimisticAddUserToCache()}>Add User to cache</button>
      <ol>
        {data?.users.map(user => {
          return <li key={user.id}>{user.firstname}</li>;
        })}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useUserList**

```js
const GET_USER_LIST = gql`
  query Users {
    users {
      id
      firstname
    }
  }
`;

export const useUserList = () => {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_USER_LIST, {
    pollInterval: 4000 // It does poll (check chromes's network tab), but it doesn't seem to overwrite the cache
  });
  const client = useApolloClient();

  const optimisticAddUserToCache = () => {
    const newUser: any = {
      id: `userId-${Math.random()}`,
      firstname: "JOHN DOE",
      __typename: "User"
    };

    const currentUserList = client.readQuery({ query: GET_USER_LIST }).users;

    // This works, it does add a user, and UI refreshes.
    client.writeQuery({
      query: GET_USER_LIST,
      data: {
        users: [newUser, ...currentUserList]
      }
    });
  };

  return { optimisticAddUserToCache, loading, error, data, refetch };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working as expected** (almost)

Polled response arrives always with **the same data** ...

... **doesn't result in write to cache** (no content compared) ...

... no data change in cache ...

... `data` property (from `useQuery`) not updated ...

... no `data` updated, no component rerendering.

**For optimistic update working you need a real mutation**, real [persisted] change on remote datasource ... propagated to next polled responses.

Comment: This is a short version of a huge app I'm working on. In the app, I'm doing exactly the same,and it works sometimes, other time no. I have no clue why. But I can tell you that I never use a mutation to the data. Why "... doesn't result in write to cache (no content compared) ..."? Poll data is actually not the same as the data in the cache and hence it should compare? I'm pretty sure there is a solution without the use of mutation, as I said I don't use them and it works intermittently in my app.

Comment: Polled data is equal to earlier polled data ... response data not compared to cache entry... probably it should be compared (post an issue on github?) ... external source of mutations? why not use subscriptions (instead of polling)?

Comment: I posted on github as well just in case. I'm only using GraphQL to read data, not to write, hence why I'm not using mutations at all. We do have subscriptions as well, but in this particular case, Im really trying to understand how the cache works, so unless the way I'm doing is strictly impossible (which I don't think so, as I said I have this half working on my main app), I'd really like to make my example work.

Comment: Looks related to https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6925